# Is there any way to split commands between different shards

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently making a bot to spread over a couple servers of my discord community, and I want to be able to broadcast a message to every server with a command. I have tried to figure out how to do this and I have not found anything about it.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @D.L I have not tried anything so far, it is not a problem it is a question. I didn't know I was not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean about splitting commands between shards however to send a message to every guild you can try iterating through each server the bot is in and assuming you do not have a specific channel you want to send a message to you can then iterate through the server's channels to find one you can message. It would look something like this:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

# Bot Setup
intents = discord.Intents.default() # Gives bot default intents
intents.message_content = True # Enables the bot to read message content

bot_prefix = commands.when_mentioned_or('-') # Prefix for the bot
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix, intents=intents, case_insensitive=True) # Applies prefix and intents

token = "<BOT_TOKEN_HERE>" # You should always store this is a file that cannot be accessed by everyone to keep it secure

# Commands for bot to execute
@bot.command(name="broadcast",
             description="Broadcast a message to all servers the bot is in")
async def broadcast_message(ctx: commands.Context, *, message):
    for guild in bot.guilds: # iterate over all servers the bot is in
        for channel in guild.text_channels: # iterate over all channels the bot can see in the server
            try:
                await channel.send(message) # Try to send message in the channel
            except Exception:
                continue # Move onto the next channel if an exception occurs
            else:
                break # Stop iterating over channels once message is successfully sent

# Run the bot using it's token
bot.run(token)
```

Comment: where is `bot` defined ?  what is the structure of bot ? this answer does not make sense to me - maybe it is incomplete ?

Comment: @D.L Thank you for your feedback. I have updated the solution I have given to add additional clarity